# Custom Annotated class with default metadata

Tags: python, annotations, mypy

I'm trying to develop a custom [Annotated](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Annotated) class...

Annotated allows to add some metadata to type hint that can be checked at runtime:

```
from typing import Annotated

some: Annotated[int, 'must be even']
```

so metadata is always required - but I want to develop a similar type that initialises metadata with some default value

```
some: MyAnnotated[int] # <- this must now must be equal to Annotated[int, '<default-meta>']
```

I'm able to make it work with this code:

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Annotated, Any

T = TypeVar('T')


class MyAnnotated(Generic[T]):
    @classmethod
    def __class_getitem__(cls, param: Any) -> T:
        if isinstance(param, tuple):
            return Annotated[param[0], param[1]]  # type: ignore
        return Annotated[param, '<default-meta>']  # type: ignore


assert MyAnnotated[int, 'my-meta'] == Annotated[int, 'my-meta']
assert MyAnnotated[int] == Annotated[int, '<default-meta>']
```

this works as expected - but editors (VScode) does not understand it and cannot add autocompletion:

[image]

while works fine with default Annotated class:

[image]

Comment: Sounds similar to [PEP 696 – Type defaults for TypeVarLikes](https://peps.python.org/pep-0696/)

Answer (score 2):

This function can be directly completed by combining `TypeVar` and `Annotated`:

```
>>> from typing import TypeVar, Annotated
>>> T = TypeVar('T')
>>> MyAnnotated = Annotated[T, 'must be even']
>>> MyAnnotated
typing.Annotated[~T, 'must be even']
>>> MyAnnotated[int]
typing.Annotated[int, 'must be even']
```

Example from the link you provided:

> - `Annotated` can be used with nested and generic aliases:
>
> ```
> @dataclass
> class MaxLen:
>     value: int
>
> T = TypeVar("T")
> Vec: TypeAlias = Annotated[list[tuple[T, T]], MaxLen(10)]
>
> assert Vec[int] == Annotated[list[tuple[int, int]], MaxLen(10)]
> ```

Pycharm can understand it correctly, and VScode should also be able to:
[image: Pycharm correctly understood it]

Comment: Thank you, but this does not allow to override like this:  `vec_20: Vec[int, MaxLen(20)]`

Answer (score 0):

I have divided my solutions into three distinct parts. Finally, I have provided a conclusion summarizing the findings:

**Type-aliasing for the default metadata**

Actually, I recommend using type aliasing and asking the user to utilize your alias to prevent code duplication and encapsulate the default value:

```
# my_annotated.py

from typing import TypeAlias, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")
DefaultAnnotated: TypeAlias = Annotated[T, "default-meta"]

def foo(x: DefaultAnnotated[str]):
    x.capitalize()

def bar(x: Annotated[str, "custom-meta"]):
    x.capitalize()
```

**Utilizing `pyi` files for better IDE support**

I understand that you want to achieve encapsulation and provide the user with a single point of entry for annotation. So, you can enrich your solution with `pyi` files to inform the IDE and type-checkers that the `MyAnnotated` type is also an `Annotated`. It helps the IDE to auto-complete but **doesn't work** with the type-checkers when using the custom metadata:

```
# my_annotated.pyi

from typing import TypeAlias, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")
MyAnnotated: TypeAlias = Annotated[T, "default-meta"]  # Not working for the MyAnnotated[str, "custom-meta"]
```

[image: The pyi solution informs the IDE for auto-completion but doesn't work with the custom metadata.]

Additionally, it is **not possible** to utilize the new `TypeVarTuple` feature to emulate the variadic behavior of `Annotated` metadata arguments (visit the [documentation](https://docs.python.domainunion.de/3/library/typing.html#typing.Annotated) for more information):

```
# my_annotated.pyi

from typing import TypeAlias, TypeVar, TypeVarTuple

T = TypeVar("T")
Vs = TypeVarTuple("Vs")
MyAnnotated: TypeAlias = Annotated[T, *Vs]  # TypeVarTuple doesn't work with the Annotated type
```

**Making your solution Mypy friendly**

Regardless of the previous part, you can make your solution Mypy-friendly by implementing a simple Mypy plugin:

```
# mypy.ini or other MyPy configuration-supported files.

[mypy]
plugins = my_annotated_mypy_plugin.py
```

```
# my_annotated_mypy_plugin.py

from mypy.plugin import Plugin, AnalyzeTypeContext

def my_annotated_type_analyze_callback(context: AnalyzeTypeContext):
    return context.api.analyze_type(context.type.args[0])

class MyAnnotatedMypyPlugin(Plugin):
    def get_type_analyze_hook(self, fullname: str):
        if fullname.endswith("MyAnnotated"):
            return my_annotated_type_analyze_callback
        return None

def plugin(version: str):
    # ignore version argument if the plugin works with all Mypy versions.
    return MyAnnotatedMypyPlugin
```

**Conclusion**

The simplest approach is to use type-aliasing for the default metadata. However, if you still prefer your solution, you can enhance IDE support and ensure compatibility with Mypy by combining the `pyi` solution with the Mypy plugin.